# rectangle colision detection SDL 2.0

Tags: c++, sdl, rectangles

I am having a problem with rectangle colision, here its the algorithm:

I detect if r1(renctangle 1) is above of r2(rectangle 2):

```
int BottomA = A.x+A.h;
int TopB = B.x;

if(TopB>BottomA)
{
Gravity();
}
```

But overlaps each other, i have tested with limiting the comprobation 60 times in a second, or without limitation of time, in the 2 cases overlaps (10 or 15 pixels, sometimes less). and the overlaps breaks the code of lateral colision.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, collision detection is nothing related with SDL. SDL only show things.

It seems you are working with axis aligned boxes. Collision detection for Axis-aligned box is the simplest condition. You just check them in the two axis (or three if you work in 3D). If any of the axis is not overlapping, the two boxes are not overlapping.

```
bool axis_check(int a_min, int a_max, int b_min, int b_max)
{
    if (a_max<b_min || b_max<a_min) return false;
    else return true;
}

bool box_collision(int a_x_min, int a_x_max, int a_y_min, int a_y_max,
                   int b_x_min, int b_x_max, int b_y_min, int b_y_max)
{
    if (axis_check(a_x_min, a_x_max, b_x_min, b_x_max)
     && axis_check(a_y_min, a_y_max, b_y_min, b_y_max))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

If you have so many objects in your scene, you can use space subdivision methods. There are many space subdivision methods, such as recursively dividing into two subspaces, recursively into eight subspaces, or into grids.

Comment: In addition, if you just want something ready-to-use, you can use a physics engine. They will correctly solve the collision, dynamics, and stability between touching objects.

Comment: first thanks for the answer, but the problem with that algorithm is that i need to know where are colliding the rectangles, if collide in the top or the left or the right or the bottom, i have thinking in use box2d,but i have to eliminate so much of my code.

Comment: @UnDesconocido Do you mean the position of the overlapping part? That is also very simple: if two axis-aligned boxes are overlapping, for each axis, the overlapped part is from the higher min value, to the lower max value.

Comment: thanks for the advise, i am starting to use Box2D, will simplify this.